# AAAttribution.attributionToken() produces Error posting to Attribution server

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use the `AdServices` framework in my app but I keep getting an error.

1. I've added AdServices as a framework
2. I've imported it
3. I try calling `let token = try AAAttribution.attributionToken()`

When running on device, this fails with the `internalError` code, saying `Error posting to Attribution server`.

Why? Nowhere online explains why this could be or how to fix it. I'm running in debug mode, could it be that?

On the simulator it's even worse and can't generate a token, but I'm not too bothered about that.

Comment: It's literally the error that I posted

Comment: `let attributionToken = try AAAttribution.attributionToken()`
works for me on the real device, I get the token. For emulator it throws exception.

Comment: btw, there's a nice manual at https://dev.to/pauladozsa/how-to-add-apple-search-ads-attribution-to-your-ios-app-4p2g